# Passing path to current_page method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actionview, actionviewhelper

I have a helper method to help to determine whether or not a navigation menu item should be active/inactive.

```
  def events_nav_link
    nav_item = 'Events'

    if current_page?(events_path) # additional conditions here
      # do nothing
    else
      nav_item = link_to nav_item, events_path
    end

    content_tag(:li, nav_item + vertical_divider, :class => 'first')
  end
```

I want this link to be inactive not only for the events_path page, but for other pages as well.  Problem is that I don't know what param to pass the current_page?(path) method based on this route:

map.list_events '/events/:league/:year/:month/:day', :controller => 'events', :action => 'list'

This route generates a path such as /pow or /chow/2011/09/25. Leagues can be pow, chow or wow.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you could use a gem like [simple_navigation](https://github.com/andi/simple-navigation) to render this kind of menu.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at the gem. Plan to try it out at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like unobtrusive JS approach with add/remove classes and unwrap() deactivated links, but it requries specific rules.

The Rails way is to use **link_to_unless_current** built-in helper to highlight and unlink on current page href.

Comment: Yes, I use link_to_unless_current for majority of cases, but for my issue, which involves nested menus, ajax, and other goodness, I need a solution to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

**application_helper.rb:**

```
  def already_here?(this_controller,this_action)
    controller_name == this_controller && action_name == this_action ? true : false
  end
```

**in a view:**

```
<%= already_here?("users","index") ? "Manage Users" : link_to("Manage Users", users_path, :title => "Manage Users.") %>
```

Of course, you can abstract it further by passing the title of the link and path to the helper if you want, but that's a bit of a hassle (to me).

**UPDATE: never mind, see mikhailov's answer- much cleaner (why reinvent the wheel?) :)**

Comment: There is a built-in helper **link_to_unless_current**

Comment: Thanks!  I've been using Rails for a long time and never noticed that one.  Can you post it as an answer so that I can +1 you?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [named routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes). In your routes.rb file, add

```
:as => :foo
```

after the route. Then use

```
if current_page(events_path) || current_page(foo_path)
```

in your condition.